# Can I mak more efficient code for getting diagonal sum in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

I've solved this problem by using for loops of row then column. But I wonder if there's more Pythonic way? Thanks.

Problem - give a 2D matrix, get the two diagonal sums.  For example:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]]
get_diag(matrix) # 25
```

Comment: You only need one loop to go over rows. For the diagonal elements, `rowIndex == colIndex`. Also, how can we tell you a _more pythonic way_ than your attempt if you don't include your attempt in the question?

Comment: Perhaps a list comprehension can work here.

Comment: @RobertDodier a list comprehension is essentially syntactic sugar for a loop.

Comment: Well, that's the reason for using it, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use slices on the flattened matrix to perform the sum over iterators (i.e. without using indexes):

```
from itertools import chain,islice
def sumDiag(M):
    D  = len(M)
    S  = sum(islice(chain.from_iterable(M),0,None,D+1))           # main
    S += sum(islice(chain.from_iterable(reversed(M)),0,None,D+1)) # inv
    return S - M[D//2][D//2]*(D%2)  # subtract center if double counted
```

output:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]]

print(sumDiag(matrix)) #25


matrix = [[1,2,3,3],
          [4,5,6,0],
          [7,8,9,2],
          [4,0,2,2]]

print(sumDiag(matrix)) #38
```

Alternatively you could generate the indexes and use them to get the items to add up. Not sure that this is more "Pythonic" though:

```
def sumDiag(M):
    return sum(matrix[r][r]+matrix[-r-1][r] for r in range(len(M))) \
           - M[len(M)//2][len(M)//2]*(len(M)%2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not more pythonic (because it gets convoluted to know what happens - a for loop with just a range would be far clearer), but to avoid doing explicit for loops you can use `reduce` - one part of the state tracks the sum, the other tracks the current offset.

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[x[1]], x[1]+1), a, (0, 0))
(15, 3)
```

`x[0]` is the current sum, `x[1]` is the current offset into the matrix row. `x[0] + y[x[1]]` adds the current element to the sum, while `x[1]+1` increments the current index into each list.

Swap the last parameter in the initializer with a `len(..) - 1`  and use `-1` inside the reduce function to get the other diagonal instead.

To do both diagonals in the same reduce call:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[x[1]] + y[len(a) - x[1] - 1], x[1] + 1), a, (0, 0))
```

However, I'm not sure if the sum in your example is correct; usually you'd consider both diagonals independently, and the sum would be 1 + 5 + 9 = 15, 15 + (3 + 5 + 7) = 30, not 25. The question doesn't specify anything in regards to that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Comment: This does not give the asked `sums`? - two diagnoals?

Comment: @DanielHao I wrote how you could do it, but sure, I'll add a one step solution as well.

Comment: Got this result - ` (30, 3)` Is this you expected?

Comment: In my question I've clearly stated the results is 25.  So I'm not sure why it's interpreted differently.... Thanks